# set parent dropdownlist of CascadingDropDown on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I have have 2 DropDownList controls with CascadingDropDown

I need set data to the first dropdownlist on server side
if i do this, and when i get page on client side, the first DropDownList without data
 that i set on server side

Thanks for any help

```
//client

  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAjaxManufacturer" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDownManufacturer" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="ddlAjaxManufacturer" Category="Make" PromptText="....." ServicePath="../../Ajax.asmx"
        ServiceMethod="GetMakes"  />
    <asp:DropDownList BackColor="white" ID="ddlAjaxModel" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDownModel" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddlAjaxModel"
        ParentControlID="ddlAjaxManufacturer" PromptText="....." ServiceMethod="GetModelsForMake"
        ServicePath="../../Ajax.asmx" Category="Model" />



//server


     ddlAjaxManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem("...", "", true));
                ddlAjaxManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem("11", "ford", true));
                ddlAjaxManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem("22", "bmw", true));
```

Comment: please show some code how you are doing it and how you are setting up cascade behaviour. Maybe something is resetting it on server itself or on client side when you setup things.

Answer (score 2):

What your trying to do may work but in a different scenario.
have you tried to use a web service to populate your dropdownlists? as far as i know CascadingDropDown works with a web service in order to populate the drop down buttons using ajax, did you see this video ?

http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/use-aspnet-ajax-cascading-drop-down-control-to-access-a-database

it shows how CascadingDropDown extender works